# Picklist Sum Formula Question (shortened)

Tags: formula, picklist

I have created the below-pasted formula to SUM the numeric picklist values and the compiled size is 6,217 characters to a maximum of 5000. How can I rectify?

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Form__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Form__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Contract_Language__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Contract_Language__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_License_Grant__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_License_Grant__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Content_Options__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Content_Options__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Exclusivity__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Exclusivity__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Term__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Term__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Termination__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Termination__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Pricing_for_Multiyear__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Pricing_for_Multiyear__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Payment_Terms__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Payment_Terms__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Invoicing__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Invoicing__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Service_Level_Agreement__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Service_Level_Agreement__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Rep_Warranty__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Rep_Warranty__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Limitation_of_Liability__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Limitation_of_Liability__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Indemnity_Hold_Harmless__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Indemnity_Hold_Harmless__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Assignment__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Assignment__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Code_App_Ownership__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Code_App_Ownership__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Data_Ownership_if_SVU__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Data_Ownership_if_SVU__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Change_of_Control__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Change_of_Control__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Choice_of_Law_Venue__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Choice_of_Law_Venue__c)))+ 
IF(ISPICKVAL(CR_Insurance_Obligations__c, ""), 0, VALUE(TEXT(CR_Insurance_Obligations__c)))
```

Comment: even if u reduce the size for now, its never easy to maintain. you shd consider moving to either visual flow or trigger and update a number field instead of using a formula field

Comment: I am not familiar with how to use a trigger with this data to accomplish this. Can you assist?

Comment: Let me know if my answer below works by the way.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I took out white space characters and switched ISPICKVAL to TEXT.

```
IF(TEXT(CR_Form__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Form__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Contract_Language__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Contract_Language__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_License_Grant__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_License_Grant__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Content_Options__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Content_Options__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Exclusivity__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Exclusivity__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Term__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Term__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Termination__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Termination__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Pricing_for_Multiyear__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Pricing_for_Multiyear__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Payment_Terms__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Payment_Terms__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Invoicing__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Invoicing__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Service_Level_Agreement__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Service_Level_Agreement__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Rep_Warranty__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Rep_Warranty__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Limitation_of_Liability__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Limitation_of_Liability__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Indemnity_Hold_Harmless__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Indemnity_Hold_Harmless__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Assignment__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Assignment__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Code_App_Ownership__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Code_App_Ownership__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Data_Ownership_if_SVU__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Data_Ownership_if_SVU__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Change_of_Control__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Change_of_Control__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Choice_of_Law_Venue__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Choice_of_Law_Venue__c)))+IF(TEXT(CR_Insurance_Obligations__c)="",0,VALUE(TEXT(CR_Insurance_Obligations__c)))
```

Comment: Too long. 6217, compiled.